# Casting Object depending on its type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, casting

I made a validation method for business rules that are not verified from my rules in the model, but I'm having a problem to make it work. Since there are two possible scenarios(customer or seller registration), they need to be treated separately in their own views and models. The seller registration inherits from customer registration for the basic info, so all fields in customer are also in seller. But since I'm working with 2 different models, even though both have the same fields that I'm doing the validation upon, I needed to use `Object` to use the same validation method. But unfortunately I'm having trouble to do so.

```
[CustomHandleError]
private bool ValidateRegistrationForm (Object registerViewModelObject) {
    if (registerViewModelObject is RegisterViewModel)
    {
        RegisterViewModel registerViewModel = 
            (RegisterViewModel)registerViewModelObject;
    }
    else
    {
        RegisterSellerViewModel registerViewModel = 
            (RegisterSellerViewModel)registerViewModelObject;
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string [] names = registerViewModel.Name.Split (
            new string [] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (names.Length == 1)
            ModelState.AddModelError ("Name", "Fill your full name");

        if (CustomerUtilities.IsCpf (registerViewModel.Identity) == false)
            ModelState.AddModelError ("Identity", "Invalid CPF value");

        if (this.AuthenticatorService.IsExistentUser (registerViewModel.Email))
            ModelState.AddModelError ("Email", "Email already registered");
    }
}
```

As you can see, after the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` the IntelliSense doesn't find registerViewModel in the current context. I wonder why this happens, since that variable is defined inside the if AND the else above, so there is no way to reach that code without it being defined.

Is there any workaround for this(other than creating a new method or passing 2 variables)?

Comment: Paste your code here as a text, not as an image.

Comment: Pasting the code as a code block will allow you to get better answers, since it will be easier to produce a correct example for you.

Comment: The quick fix is to copy and paste the code in the if and else blocks.  The issue is that there is no common base class for the registrations or that inheritance is not being used properly (a seller registration does not seem to be a kind of customer registration so inheritance will be awkward). You've got to do some design work to fix this.

Comment: With @Mikhail Vladimirov's help, I got it to text. Thanks Mikhail

Comment: I only posted as image earlier to show the error part

Comment: @leobelones You can also consider my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to have two separate variables then declare both outside of the if statement and test for null after.

```
RegisterViewModel registerViewModel;
RegisterSellerViewModel sellerModel; 

if (registerViewModelObject is RegisterViewModel)
{
    registerViewModel = (RegisterViewModel)registerViewModelObject;
}
else
{
    sellerViewModel = (RegisterSellerViewModel)registerViewModelObject;
}
```

However, defining an interface to use instead of Object would be the better option.

```
public interface IRegisterViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public ... Identity {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class RegisterViewModel : IRegisterViewModel
{
    ...
}

public class RegisterSellerViewModel : IRegisterViewModel
{
    ...
}
```

Then use ValidateRegistrationForm(IRegisterViewModel registerViewModel) and you can get rid of the if statement entirely.

Comment: the problem with this approach is the code duplication inside the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` block. I was looking for something neater and cleaner. TY for the help though

Comment: I added in the interface way of doing it, that may be more to your (and my) liking.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `RegisterViewModel` outside of the if block scope, and assign it within the if block.

```
RegisterViewModel registerViewModel;
if (registerViewModelObject is RegisterViewMOdel)
{
     registerViewModel = // ...
}
else
{
     registerViewModel = // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but if it was to be like that I wouldn't need the Object. The problem is that there are 2 different models, in which I choose in runtime which to define.

Comment: Then you probably will need to have a common base class or interface that lets you perform the code in the ModelState.IsValid if clause.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `RegisterViewModel` outside from your `if` statemtent. And make assignment inside your `if` statement.

Like;

```
RegisterViewModel registerViewModel;
if(...)
{
  //make your assigment here.
}
```

Comment: as I stated on the other answer, I don't know which model to use therefore I can't declare it outside the if.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to extract methods that are common for `RegisterViewModel` and `RegisterSellerViewModel` into an interface and implement it in both classes.  Then cast `registerViewModelObject` to this interface regardless of its actual type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs since you don't have a single variable defined in the main scope of the function. In the way that you have written your code, you define two variables that are inside different scopes.

How I would go about with the solution:

I would make a base class.

```
class RegisterModel
{
   public string Name;
   public IdentifyType Identify;
   public string Email;
}
```

And then both your classes can inherit from the base class. Like this:

```
class RegisterViewModel
   : RegisterModel
{...}
class RegisterSellerViewModel
   : RegisterModel
{...}
```

Now you can actually covert the Object variable in your function a single time. Like this:

```
private bool Validate(Object viewModel)
{
   var castViewModel = (RegisterModel)viewModel;
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Note that this will cause a run-time error if viewModel is not of type RegisterModel.